# Iterate over an ImmutableSet and ImmutableList and mutate objects

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have following setup (i.e `Entity` is a `JPA2` entitiy and `entities` is a collection)

```
class Entity {
    Set<SubEntity> entities = new HashSet<>();
    public Set<SubEntity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }
}

class SubEntity {
     Double value;
     // setters and getters ommitted
}

class SomeLibrary {
    public static List<Double> transform(List<Double> values) {
         // transform values and return a new list with transfored values
    }
}
```

I need to transform the `value` field in my `SubEntity` by using an external library that takes a `List<Doubles>` and returns a new list with the transformed values. Afterwards I need to update the `SubEntity` with the transofmred value.

Because `Set` does not guaranetee iteration order I first convert it to an `ImmutableSet` and use `Collections2.transform` to create an `ImmutableList` of the values.

```
ImmutableSet<SubEntity> entities = ImmutableSet.copyOf(entity.getEntities());
ImmutableList<Double> values = ImmutableList.copyOf(Collections2.transform(entities, (e) -> e.getValue()))
```

At this point I assume that the items in both collections (`entities` and `values` match up, like when I zip both lists)

```
List<Double> transformedValues = SomeLibrary.transform(values);
Iterator<SubEntity> entityIterator = entities.iterator();
Iterator<Double> valueIterator = transformedValues.iterator();
while(entityIterator.hasNext() && valueIterator.hasNext()) {
    SubEntity entity = entityIterator.next();
    Double value = valueIterator.next();
    entity.setValue(value);
}
```

So there are two questions:

1. Can I safely mutate a field of an object that is part of an immutable collection while I am iterating over it ?
2. When I am iterating over the `ImmutableSet` of the `SubEntity` and `List` of transformed values, I assume that the values match up. Is this guaranteed when I am using immutable collections and the `transform` function?

Comment: would´t a `Map` be more suitable to not be in the need that both `List` are having the same order?

Comment: Safely mutating objects already in a `Collection`, whatever that collection, is a contradiction in words. You realize that, right?

Comment: @KevinEsche: Wouldn't I need two `Maps` or if I only use one `Map` also depend on iteration order ?

Comment: `"Because Set does not guaranetee iteration order..."`  There *are* sets that will maintain a specific order.  LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order and TreeSet will order by a Comparator without the need to convert to and from ImmutableSets.

Comment: @fge: Why so ? I was assuming that chaning the structure of a `Collection` is problematic but chaning the state of the objects inside a collection might be ok ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, unless the double value is used to compute the hashCode of the entity, and the collection uses the hashCode. But I really don't see why you're using a Set here, and why it needs to be immutable. Just using `new ArrayList<>(entity.getEntities())` would suffice to have a reliable, consistent iteration order.
2. Yes, since the javadoc of ImmutableSet says: *A high-performance, immutable Set with reliable, user-specified iteration order*.